# ms sql server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i m creating a library management software using vb.net and ms sqlserver 2008 for the first time. and well i have following question----

1-- do i have to create sql authentication or windows authentication on server and this database should be accessed by any user who has access to the administrator user on **OTHER** computer.

2--  i have to transfer this software(all files including database) to the other computers, so how to perform installation  and uninstallation on other pc using vb.net

thanking u in advance ...

Comment: use `sql authentication`. you can't connection using `windows authentication` for remote connections

Comment: @JohnWoo Actually it **is** possible.

Comment: then how? actually i want to know it. using `VPN`? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I use for my test server following connection string:

```
Server=sqlServer;Database=APL;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

With me it works. My setup is as follows: No Domain, database server, client server. Same network, database server has user with name: x and password: y. Same for the client server.

This should work if you are using a domain server.